How to manage synonyms of an entity
How to manage synonyms for an entity (say a Sports Team) which can be referenced by multiple names while searching
The following tags refer to Dallas Mavericks team - https://www.mavs.com/
Mavs, dallasmavs, DALLAS MAVERICKS

The following tags refer to Trail Blazers team - https://www.nba.com/blazers
Portland Trail Blazers, Trail Blazers 

The following tags refer to Los Angeles Lakers team - https://www.nba.com/lakers/
lakers, Lakers

The following tags refer to Phoenix Suns team
phoenix suns, Phoenix Suns

I would like to use the synonyms capability to match an entity (say a Sports team), based on the above tags. How do I identify this as a first class document allowing me to search by any of the tags, so that the main team can be returned on the result. How to model this entity in Elasticsearch and setup synonyms with ease

Di you check this documentation ? Can you try as mentioned in documentation and let us know if you face any issue after that.

@SagarPatel we are using a file to manage synonyms which is not scalable as we have to upload this multiple times to keep the values current.

You can defined as synonym set and then assign that value to index mapping and use synonym set API to refresh it as well. Please check this documentation. Please let me know if this helps you.

Tldr;
As mentioned in the comment you might want to look at the synonyms API which made it way in the stack starting version 8.10
Creating synonyms is as easy as this:
PUT _synonyms/my-synonyms-set
{
  "synonyms_set": [
    {
      "id": "test-1",
      "synonyms": "hello, hi, ciao"
    }
  ]
}

Demo
Based on your specific case I am creating the following synonyms
PUT _synonyms/sport_teams_synonyms
{
  "synonyms_set": [
    {
      "synonyms": "dallas mavericks => mavs, dallasmavs, mavericks"
    },
    {
        "synonyms": "portland trail blazers, trail blazers => ptb"
    }
  ]
}

Then create the following index
PUT sport_teams_match
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "sts_filter": {
          "type": "synonym_graph",
          "synonyms_set": "sport_teams_synonyms",
          "updateable": true
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "sport_teams_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "sts_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "team_1": {
        "type": "text",
        "search_analyzer": "sport_teams_analyzer"
      },
      "team_2": {
        "type": "text",
        "search_analyzer": "sport_teams_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}

Loaded some documents
PUT _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "sport_teams_match"} }
{ "team_1" : "mavs", "team_2": "lakers" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "sport_teams_match"} }
{ "team_1" : "trail blazers", "team_2": "lakers" }

The following search queries should find you the first document
GET sport_teams_match/_search?q=team_1:"Mavericks"
GET sport_teams_match/_search?q=team_1:"Dallas Mavericks"

Awesome let try with Trail Blazers ?
GET sport_teams_match/_search?q=team_1:"Trail Blazers"

Uhuuuu not working ?? why ??
The _analyze API to the rescue. This api return given a specific analyzer pipeline and some text, the token extracted.
POST sport_teams_match/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "sport_teams_analyzer",
  "text":     "Trail Blazers"
}

POST sport_teams_match/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text":     "trail blazers"
}

You will see that:

sport_teams_analyzer => ptb
standard => trail, blazers

How can we fix this ?
ptb might not be such a good synonym after all ?
